# jqplotToImage fails when called via HTMLUnit

Tags: java, htmlunit, jqplot

I have a web page that uses jqplot for charts and Google Datatable to display the data in a table format. I also have an "Export" hyperlink in the webpage for generate a PDF copy of the webpage for download. My export code looks as follows:

```
function exportPDF() {
    var img = $('#clicks_chart_div').jqplotToImage(0, 0); 
    if (img) {
        var imgTag = $('<img id="ccanvasimage">');
        imgTag.attr('src', img.toDataURL("image/png"));
        imgTag.attr('width', 450);
        imgTag.attr('height', 320);
        $('#clicks_chart_div').replaceWith(imgTag);
    } else {
        alert('could not get image');
    }
    $('#src').val(document.documentElement.innerHTML);
    $('#frmSource').submit();
  }
```

This code works well in a browser and downloads the respective PDF. However, when I invoke the same page via HTMLUnit, the call "var img = $('#clicks_chart_div').jqplotToImage(0, 0);" is not able to generate the image and goes to the else part "alert('could not get image');" Thus, the resulting PDF just contains the Datatable and none of the charts.

Any idea on why the call jqplotToImage fails? FWIW, the code for jqplotToImage is included via an external script as follows:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/export-jqplot-to-png.js"></script>
```

Thanks.

Comment: @Boro I have given the relevant code for the "exportPDF" function. Do you want me to add anything specific?

Comment: @Ananth How to you export that image to the pdf or the excel. Can you post the code? I am confused how to get the source of that image at runtime. Thankx